# The connection"....." is not found.This error is thrown by connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have this error during my package execution.This error doesnt stop my data flow though but i want to get rid of this error as this might effect in near future.All my packages use the ssis logging to log the errors.Even though i have my connection (in this case i am using project level connections) exist on project.It still throws a error.

I have found a solution that when we change the project level connections manager to package level connection i dont get any issues(which is not recommended in our environment).So i request all you sql users to help me out.

Thank you,
[image: Error ..!!]

Comment: Are you using some expression to initialize the connection string?

Comment: This error suggest that you are assigned a variable in Connection property and it is not found.

Comment: Just a regular oledb connection without any varibles and expressions